# Invalid column names when using foreign keys

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have ran into this problem before. I just cannot remember what it was that was causing it. I am also trying to implement this with AspNetUsers and AspNetRoles tables. I am not sure if this is part of the issue or not.

So here is my Model:

```
public class MenuPermission
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string MenuId { get; set; }
    public virtual Menu Menu_MenuId { get; set; }
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual RoleDTO Role_RoleId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ExpandedUserDTO User_UserId { get; set; }
    public int? SortOrder { get; set; }
    public bool IsForNavBar { get; set; }
    public bool IsCreate { get; set; }
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }
    public bool IsUpdate { get; set; }
    public bool IsDelete { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the foreign keys in SQL Server:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MenuPermission] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.MenuPermission_dbo.AspNetRoles_RoleId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([RoleId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetRoles] ([Id])
                ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MenuPermission] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.MenuPermission_dbo.AspNetRoles_RoleId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MenuPermission]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.MenuPermission_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MenuPermission] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.MenuPermission_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId]
```

The error I am getting when I run the project is:

> SqlException: Invalid column name 'Role_RoleId_Id'.
>   Invalid column name 'User_UserId_UserName'.

This is the line of code that is causing the issue:

```
var global = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(cacheItemKey);
        if (global == null)
        {
        LINE OF ERROR --> global = db.MenuPermissions.Where(i => i.RoleId == RoleId || i.UserId == userId).ToArray();
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheItemKey, global, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        }
```

EDIT: This is the code that is stems from:

```
public ActionResult GetGrid()
    {
        var tak = db.MenuPermissions.ToArray();

        var result = from c in tak
                     select new string[] { c.Id.ToString(), Convert.ToString(c.Id),
        Convert.ToString(c.Menu_MenuId !=null?c.Menu_MenuId.MenuText:""),
        Convert.ToString(c.Role_RoleId.RoleName),
        Convert.ToString(c.User_UserId !=null?c.User_UserId.UserName:""),
        Convert.ToString(c.SortOrder),
        Convert.ToString(c.IsForNavBar),
        Convert.ToString(c.IsAdd),
        Convert.ToString(c.IsCreate),
        Convert.ToString(c.IsRead),
        Convert.ToString(c.IsUpdate),
        Convert.ToString(c.IsDelete),
         };
        return Json(new { aaData = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Edit: User and Roles View Models

```
public class RoleDTO
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Role Name")]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}

public class ExpandedUserDTO
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "User Id")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Email address is required")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 8)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Password is required")]

    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Lockout End Date UTC")]
    public DateTime? LockoutEndDateUtc { get; set; }
    public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<UserRolesDTO> Roles { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Roles is required")]
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

UPDATE:
I added a new ViewModel UsersDTO with only the Id and Username. Id is Key. I do not have the error any longer on the user side.

Still have issue with Roles...

UPDATE:

Here is what is Working right now:

Added UserDTO

```
public virtual UserDTO User_UserId { get; set; }
```

Model:

```
      public class UserDTO
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "User Id")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }    
}
```

Added Foreign Key to:

```
[ForeignKey("RoleId")]
public virtual RoleDTO Role_RoleId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Could you post your User and Role model classes also - at least the part which highlights the primary keys of respective classes?

Comment: The only models i have are ViewModels for these. Entity Framework creates these when you select to use multiple users. I am using a view model created for the Roles. That is where i am pulling from. I will post that.

Comment: I suppose it is possible to create models for AspNetUsers and AspNetRoles but i would think that is going against the Identity Grain... Is it not?

Comment: for user column error, its obvious that UserName is Key in your model and UserId is defined as FK in database

Comment: I did notice that when i posted it. But the Role has similar issue. And that has Id defined as key.

Comment: Could you decorate this property :
    public virtual RoleDTO Role_RoleId { get; set; } with [ForeignKey("RoleId ")] attribute.

Comment: So i tried that earlier with the RoleId and it did not work. I just used it for the virtual RoleDTO and it seems to be working now. Thank you for your help! I will post the Fix.

Answer (score 0):

Please decorate the property

```
public virtual RoleDTO Role_RoleId { get; set; }
```

with 
  `[ForeignKey("RoleId ")]` attribute

```
public class MenuPermission
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    // Other properties go here
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RoleId ")] 
    public virtual RoleDTO Role_RoleId { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ExpandedUserDTO User_UserId { get; set; } // this seems to be configuration issue. Database says UserId is issue but ExpandedUserDTO says UserName is key.
    // Other properties go here
}
```